# Kafka clients fails with error "Connection to node could not be established. Broker may not be available" when changing brokers' IP addresses

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I have a Kafka cluster running on Kubernetes. Kafka connect and clients uses the bootstrap server to successfully connect to the cluster. When the brokers pod get restarted they change the IP address, causing a lot of `Broker may not be available` errors:

```
Connection to node 0 
(kafka-0.kafka-cp-kafka-headless.svc.cluster.local/<ip>:9092) 
could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

My `advertised.listeners` is set to `PLAINTEXT://kafka-0.kafka-cp-kafka-headless.svc.cluster.local:9092,EXTERNAL://<host ip>:31090`.

It looks like the client ties itself to a specific IP and being unable to resolve the new IP when it change, despite having the FDQN. There is some configuration I'm missing in the server or on client side that could fix this annoying situation?

Comment: Don't expose (advertise) IPs if they can change. Connect your clients to the DNS service names or use a TCP loadbalancer

Comment: @OneCricketeer the DNS pod name `PLAINTEXT://kafka-0.kafka-cp-kafka-headless.svc.cluster.local:9092` is not enough? Should I put a service in front of a statefulset with 3 replicas?

Comment: It seems that Kafka Connect is unable to crash when the broker is unavailable.

Comment: I suspect `networkaddress.cache.ttl` does some nasty trick here with JVM clients such as Kafka Connect: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html

Comment: Seems like you're using Confluent Helm Charts (which aren't really maintained anymore, as far as I know, and have numerous github issues). Have you tried using https://Strimzi.io or looked at how it sets up Kafka endpoints for the Connect cluster?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Confluent Helm Charts, but I'm currently unable to switch to another chart. Anyway, upgrading kafka-connect to `2.1.1` (Confluent `5.1.4`) seems to solve the issue and correctly uses the DNS pod name instead of caching forever the IP.